# How do I install CLI tools "under Rosetta 2" on MacBook M1?

Tags: macos, arm, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

After getting a MacBook M1 2020 - I found most of my command line tools could no longer be installed. I presume this was because the tools were compiled to run on an Intel based chipset, and not the new Apple Chipset (citation needed).

Here is an example:

```sh
APP is not (yet) supported on ARM processors!
Rerun the APP installer under Rosetta 2.
```

**How do I install an app "under Rosetta 2"?**

Answer (score 10):

I found [the solution here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2350#issuecomment-734132550), which worked a treat.

> In Terminal, use
>
> `arch -x86_64 zsh`
>
> to start a shell under Rosetta 2

Addendum: I created a `rosetta` alias, so I can switch in the future:

```
echo 'alias rosetta="arch -x86_64 zsh"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 3):

install rosetta and skip the license agreement

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued to know more, and this is what I found:

**What's the problem ?**

> Apple released the first Macs with Apple Silicon in November 2020.
> While most apps have been updated to run natively on Apple Silicon,
> there are still some that haven’t been updated yet. That’s where
> Rosetta 2 comes in.
>
> Rosetta 2 is a translation layer for running Intel-based apps on Apple
> Silicon Macs. It uses dynamic binary translation to convert x86_64
> code to the Arm64 architecture used by the M1 and M2 chips. It allows
> these new Macs to run apps that haven’t been updated to run natively
> on Apple Silicon.

source: [howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/822889/what-is-rosetta-2-on-mac/)

**What does `arch -x86_64 zsh` mean ? or do ?**

`arch` is a command to use to display the machine architecture of the system. When used with `-x86_64`, it specifies that the following command should be executed as if the machine architecture is `x86_64`, which typically refers to a **64-bit** Intel or **AMD processor** architecture.